# AWSMobileHub Caching Images from S3 in IOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, caching, aws-mobilehub

I am trying to download an image from S3 to cache it.
This without caching is working:

```
let manager = AWSUserFileManager.defaultUserFileManager()
let content = manager.contentWithKey("public%2F" + userID + "_profile.jpg")
content.getRemoteFileURLWithCompletionHandler({[weak self](url: NSURL?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
guard let url = url else {
         print("Error getting URL for file. \(error)")
         return
         }
         let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
         imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
         })
```

And this with caching is not working:

```
      let content = manager.contentWithKey("public%2F" + userID + "_profile.jpg")
    if !content.cached {
        print("Not Cached")
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "UserIcon")
        content.downloadWithDownloadType(AWSContentDownloadType.IfNewerExists, pinOnCompletion: false, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (content: AWSContent?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                print("Cached")
                imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        })
    } else {
        print("Cached2")
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: content.cachedData)
    }
```

I get in error after completion: domain: "com.amazonaws.AWSContentManager.ErrorDomain" - code: 1

what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it out. It is necessary to use the progress!

```
 if !content.cached {
        print("Not Cached")
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "UserIcon")
        content.downloadWithDownloadType(AWSContentDownloadType.IfNewerExists, pinOnCompletion: false, progressBlock: {(content: AWSContent?, progress: NSProgress?) -> Void in
             return
            }, completionHandler: { (content: AWSContent?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
               print("Failed to download a content from a server.)")
                print("Error " + error.debugDescription)
                return
                }
            print("Cached")
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

        })
    } else {
        print("Cached2")
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: content.cachedData)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It could because it's downloading same content while the other one is still being downloaded. At least that's my issue.